# scanf from the buffer is not working properly

Tags: c

I will use this small part of code in my assignment but there are some problems. When I don't use `fflush(stdin)` it doesn't scan the `basetype`. But when I use `fflush(stdin)` it scans the `basetype` but the `scanf` inside the `while` loop doesn't continue to take the characters from the buffer. For example when I enter `2A`... Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int operation, basetype, number1;
    char num1;

    printf("Please enter the number of the operation you would like to perform:");
    printf("\n1. Bitwise OR\n2. Bitwise NOT\n3. Bitwise COMPARE\n4. Exit");
    scanf("%d", &operation);
    if (operation == 1) {
        printf("You chose Bitwise OR operation.");
        printf("\nPlease enter the first number:");
        scanf(" %c", &num1);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nPlease specify the base(10/16):");
        scanf("%d", &basetype);

        if (basetype == 10) {
            while (num1 != 10) {
                number1 = num1 - '0';

                if (number1 >= 1 && number1 <= 9) {
                    printf("ok");
                } else
                    printf("not ok");
                scanf("%c", &num1);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin)` has no defined behavior according to the standard. Implementations define a behavior but they do so in an inconsistent way, so NEVER USE `fflush(stdin)`. Your problem is the `'\n'` that remains unscanned, try `scanf(" %c%*c", &num1);`. You will quickly understand that `scanf()` is considerably hard to use correctly.

Comment: so what should i do to make the scanf for basetype work? It doesn't work without fflush(stdin) @IharobAlAsimi

Comment: It's just the part of the code not the whole one... it should work in operaiton 1 for now @xing

Comment: yes when i type just one character it works. The problem is when i scan multiple characters...(i should not use arrays) So it takes the first character and the other characters are in the buffer.. i wan to take them one by one in the while loop. But fflush(stdin) cleans the buffer. But without using fflush(stdin) i cant scan the basetype. So the actual qustion is, why i cant scan the basetype without using fflush(stdin)???

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler doesn't care, but us humans do) 1) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{',  unindent before every closing brace '}',  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being use.  I.E. this line: `#include <math.h>`  should be removed

Comment: `scanf("%c", &num1);` --> `scanf(" %c", &num1);`, add space.

Comment: "scanf...not working properly" is a common refrain, because scanf is a terrible tool.  You may use it a few times at university for some ungodly reason, but you will never use it again because it is fragile and impossibly complicated.  Take a stand for sanity, and stop using it.  Just say no!

Answer (score 1):

`fflush(stdin);` has undefined behavior, do not use it to attempt to *flush* the standard input buffer.  You could instead write:

```
{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue; }
```

You should also decide whether you read a number in `num1` or a digit.  `"%c"` is for reading a single character, `"%d"` to read a number in decimal format.

There is a `scanf` format tailored for your needs: `%i` converts a number encoded in a user specified base, 8, 10 or 16 depending on the initial characters, just like the C source code syntax for integer literals.

Here is a simplified program that can deal with hexadecimal input entered with a `0x` prefix, such as `0x40` for `64`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int operation, number1, number2, result;

    printf("Please enter the number of the operation you would like to perform:\n"
           "1. Bitwise OR\n"
           "2. Bitwise NOT\n"
           "3. Bitwise COMPARE\n"
           "4. Exit\n");
    if (scanf("%i", &operation) != 1)
        return 1;
    if (operation == 1) {
        printf("You chose Bitwise OR operation.\n");
        printf("Please enter the first number: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &number1) != 1)
            return 1;
        printf("Please enter the second number: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &number2) != 1)
            return 1;
        result = number1 | number2;
        printf("%d (0x%x) | %d (0x%x) = %d (0x%x)\n",
               number1, number1, number2, number2, result, result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. contains embedded comments about problems with the code
3. is organized to clearly show what each part of the code is doing
4. for `Bitwise_OR` operation clearly shows the code does nothing, especially not a bitwise OR operation

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
//#include<math.h>

enum
{
    Bitwise_OR = 1,
    Bitwise_NOT,
    Bitwise_COMPARE,
    Exit
};

int main( void )
{

    char operation;
    int basetype;
    int number1;
    char num1;

    puts("Please enter the number of the operation you would like to perform:");
    printf( "%s",
            "1. Bitwise OR\n"
            "2. Bitwise NOT\n"
            "3. Bitwise COMPARE\n"
            "4. Exit");
    if( 1 != scanf(" %c",&operation) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for operation failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    switch( operation )
    {

        case Bitwise_OR: //<-- bitwise OR never performed
            printf("You chose Bitwise OR operation.");
            printf("\nPlease enter the first number:");
            if( 1 != scanf(" %c",&num1) )
            {
                perror( "scanf for first number failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, scanf successful

            //fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nPlease specify the base(10/16):");
            if( 1 != scanf("%d", &basetype) )
            {
                perror( "scanf for base failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, scanf successful

            switch(basetype)
            {
                case 10:
                    while(num1 != 10)  //<-- user entering 0x0A is extremely unlikely
                    {
                        number1=num1-'0';  //<-- what if num1 not '0'...'9'

                        if(number1>=1 && number1<=9)
                        {
                            printf("ok");
                        }

                        else
                            printf("not ok");

                        // either retry first digit or get second digit
                        scanf(" %c",&num1); //<-- leading space to consume 'white space'
                    }
                    break;

                case 16:
                    break;

                default:
                    puts( "base must be 10 or 16" );
                    break;
            } // end switch()
            break;

        case Bitwise_NOT:
            break;

        case Bitwise_COMPARE:
            break;

        case Exit:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    } // end switch()

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```